# Where can I find traceur options

Tags: javascript, browserify, traceur

I keep getting exceptions while using es6ify and browserify. This is my gulp code:

```
es6ify.traceurOverrides = {
    asyncFunctions: true,
    freeVariableChecker: true
};

browserify(params)
    .add(es6ify.runtime)
    .transform(es6ify)
    .require(require.resolve('app/index.js'), { entry: true })
    .bundle()
    ...
    ...
```

First, I got an error regarding a file that contained:

```
import a, { func } from 'some/module';
```

The exception was:

```
Unexpected token , while parsing file: <file path>
```

For some reason this was solved when I set `freeVariableChecker` to `true`.
Now I get an error:

```
window is not defined while parsing file: <file path>
```

And I don't understand which option should fix this issue.

Any idea where I can find explanations on traceur options?
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution ? i have the same problem with rails and babel/browserify

Comment: @Lichtamberg: Nope. But maybe I can help you with Babel. What is your question?